# How to conduct mantel test with distance matrix using R with ready fst?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a fst value (molecular distance indices) between population (which is not calculate from molecular data, original raw data is misiing)
but I have got environmental data and location (including lon and lat)
I would like to use Mantel test (r is better)to conduct correlation of these distance matrix.
However, I cannot got packages go through and it seems problem is on fst table
I made a csv table as below

1   2   3   4   5   6

0.0282  0   0.0266  0.5122  0.4784  0.5553

0.057   0.0266  0   0.4426  0.4042  0.5448

0.318   0.5122  0.4426  0   0.4527  0.6017

0.3412  0.4784  0.4042  0.4527  0   0.4171

0.4462  0.5553  0.5448  0.6017  0.4171  0

And I use the code to import or calculate the dist matrix

```
library(ade4)
setwd(choose.dir())
df = read.table("hynobins_climate.csv", header= T,sep=",")
station.dists <- dist(cbind(df$lon, df$lat))
#This works fine for calculation of geo distance

fst=read.table("mtFst.csv",header=T)
mantel.rtest(station.dists, fst, nrepet = 9999)
```

It returns error message : **Error in mantel.rtest(station.dists, fst, nrepet = 9999) :
Object of class 'dist' expected**

How could I conduct my mantel test while I only have calculated fst instead of raw data (and I can conduct suite packages to generate molecular distance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution is "to create a matrix by my self"

```
cbind(c(0,0.024,    0.0414, 0.9565, 0.9802, 1),c(0.024,0,0.0403,0.9515,0.9766,0.9979),c(0.414,0.403,0,0.9396,0.9643,0.9928)........
fst[upper.tri(fst,diag=TRUE)] <- NA
fst<-as.dist(fst)
```

Then it works~!